# React web app routes not working with query string by using nginx when there is query param

Tags: nginx

What is mistake hear, I am using this to solve nginx in ubuntu
location / {
try_files $uri /index.html$is_args$args = 404;
}

Comment: I figure it out, it is mistake in argument, it is clearly mention like if there is argument then 404, so I remove 404 and it's work 

 location / { try_files $uri /index.html$is_args$args; }